# What kind of exception to raise for unknown enum value?

Tags: python, exception, enums

Assume the following class:

```
class PersistenceType(enum.Enum):
  keyring = 1
  file = 2

  def __str__(self):
    type2String = {PersistenceType.keyring: "keyring", PersistenceType.file: "file"}
    return type2String[self]

  @staticmethod
  def from_string(type):
    if (type == "keyring" ):
        return PersistenceType.keyring
    if (type == "file"):
        return PersistenceType.file
    raise ???
```

Being a python noob, I am simply wondering: what specific kind of exception should be raised here?

Comment: `AttributeError`? I am guessing this because the same type of an error shows up when you access a member that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError):

> Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as `IndexError`.

The longer answer is that almost none of that class should exist. Consider:

```
class PersistenceType(enum.Enum):
    keyring = 1
    file = 2
```

This gives you everything your customized enum does:

- To get the same result as your customised `__str__` method, just use the `name` property:

  ```
  >>> PersistenceType.keyring.name
  'keyring'
  ```
- To get a member of the enum using its name, treat the enum as a dict:

  ```
  >>> PersistenceType['keyring']
  <PersistenceType.keyring: 1>
  ```

Using the built-in abilities of `Enum.enum` gives you several advantages:

1. You're writing much less code.
2. You aren't repeating the names of the enum members all over the place, so you aren't going to miss anything if you modify it at some point.
3. Users of your enum, and readers of code that uses it, don't need to remember or look up any customized methods.

If you're coming to Python from Java, it's always worth bearing in mind that:

[**Python Is Not Java**](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html) (or, stop writing so much code)

[**Guido<sup>1</sup> has a time machine**](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/G/Guido.html) (or, stop writing so much code)

---

<sup>1</sup> … or in this case Ethan Furman, the author of the `enum` module.

Comment: Fancy. Something along the lines I was hoping for. Interestingly enough; I built my code on something some "more experienced" python people showed me long time ago. One question though: when I use the "dict" approach ... and the string is invalid ... I guess I will hit a pretty ugly exception message?

Comment: You'll get a `KeyError`, which is exactly what you want, because you'll have supplied a nonexistent key. This is better than a custom exception, because again, a) you won't have to implement and maintain it, and b) users of the class won't have to go searching to find out what it means.

Comment: Well. Yes, less code for me to maintain. But now my outer command line shell should probably catch that error, as the user doesn't know about hashes or anything. But I just found that argparse and "choices" gives me what I need there!

Comment: Yep, by all means catch `KeyError` at the point it's raised so you can show something friendlier to the user (or rely on something else e.g. argparse to do so). You'll have to catch *something* regardless, and if it's a built-in exception, that code will be clearer and more maintainable.